# can't keep cdk mat-menu in original position on page scroll

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk

I'm trying to keep angular CDK's mat-menu at a fixed position but it keeps showing event when i scroll the page.
The expected result would be to behave like other elements on the page (it means that I want it to stay on top whenever I scroll the page).
I tried to fix it with css position property but none of the solutions worked for me.
Here's a portion of my code

`.HTML`

```
<button mat-button #menuTrigger="matMenuTrigger" [matMenuTriggerFor]="VListmenu"> 
      <span >{{title}}</span>
      <fa-icon style="margin: auto 0;" class="text-white" [icon]="faChevronDown"></fa-icon>
 </button>


<mat-menu #VListmenu="matMenu" class="list-search-menu" [overlapTrigger]="false">
                              <div class="container" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">

                                    <div class="flex-zone" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">


                                        <div *ngIf="category == 'vehicule'">
                                            <label class="search-area">
                                                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                                                <input type="text" placeholder="chercher" name="search" class="search-input" (input)="readInput($event)">
                                            </label>
                                        </div>

                                        <div *ngIf="showSelect" class="float-right-select" >
                                            <mat-form-field class="event-type">
                                                <mat-select [(value)]="selectedState" (selectionChange)="onChangeState($event)" id="searchBoxValue">
                                                    <mat-option value="all">Tous</mat-option>
                                                    <mat-option value="active">Actif</mat-option>
                                                    <mat-option value="notactive">Non Actif</mat-option>
                                                </mat-select>
                                            </mat-form-field>                        
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div *ngIf="showSelectAll" class="float-right-select-all" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
                                        <!-- [indeterminate]="SelectedTypes.length > 0 && SelectedTypes.length < items.length" -->
                                        <mat-checkbox 
                                            color='warn' 
                                            [checked]="SelectedTypes.length == items.length"
                                            [indeterminate]="SelectedTypes.length > 0 && SelectedTypes.length < items.length"
                                            (change)="selectAll($event)" >
                                            Séléctionner Tous
                                        </mat-checkbox>

                                    </div>

                                        <mat-selection-list (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" disableOptionCentering class="virtual-scroll">
                                            <mat-list-item *ngFor="let item of items;let index=index;" (click)="onRowclicked(item, index, $event)" class="border border-warning title-field mb-1" [ngStyle]="{'background': item.checked? '#DAE1F7':'white'}">
                                                <mat-checkbox color='warn' (click)="onChangeCheckbox(item,index,$event)" [(ngModel)]="item.checked">
                                                    {{ item.name }}</mat-checkbox>
                                                </mat-list-item>
                                                <mat-list-item *ngIf='!allLoaded' (click)="loadMore($event)" class="border border-warning title-field mb-1 load_more_btn">
                                                    <span>
                                                        Charger plus
                                                    </span> 
                                        </mat-list-item>
                                        </mat-selection-list>

                                    </div>
                                </mat-menu>
```

Comment: Menus are placed into a container at the root of the dom tree. So your issue is probably related to conflicts with your CSS. You could try to remove all your CSS and see if it is the case.

Comment: Which angular-material version are you using? There was an issue with the scroll strategy of menus in versions < 7.2 => https://github.com/angular/components/issues/11365

Comment: I'm using material version 8.1..1